# Which mask to use for 1024 address size subnet

Tags: ip, ip-address, mask, subnet

I am trying to identify if given IPs are from same 1024 SUBNET.

- 192.168.3.1
- 192.168.2.19
- 192.168.1.1

The part I got stuck is that **SUBNET address size is 1024**.

If I am sure, by checking IP addresses we have to use mask of C class? Because IP is in range between 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.255.255.
But the problem is that I am not sure **which mask to use**.

I found on the internet table of c class addresses, but I am not sure if it's this one.

[Is MASK 255.252.0.0 ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpasM.png)

Comment: Might be better asked on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe all these IPs are from same subnet.
I used first table in https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html

Mask for each one is **255.255.252.0** (We convert mask to binary, and on the end 
we got 10000000000 - thats exactly 1024 in decimal)

Address I got for each IP after binary multiplication - 192.168.0.0